# Disposable email address given to third parties?

Tags: google-signin

Currently google single sign-on gives your real email address to everyone.  Instead it could give each party a different identifier for you, such that these third parties wouldn't be able to correlate your data.

Moreover spam could be more easily identified and stopped.  Google could manage a fleet of "salted" email addresses for each user, tracking which third parties send spam.  Signin/gmail synergy.

My question:  Does this exist already?  Why does this not already exist?  Do any other auth vendors do this?

Followup: Why is my email address even used as my primary id?  I'd rather keep it private.

Answer (score 1):

Your email is not used as a primary identifier at least not by Google. When a website such as Airbnb does an open ID connect dance with Google, Google replies with a unique identifier to Airbnb. That identifier does not mean anything to Airbnb as to what your email first name last name are. What also happens is that Airbnb can ask Google for your email and that is how they end up having your email.

Note that Apple have a privacy preserving mechanism where instead of returning your real email address they will return an Apple email address that points to your email. That gives you one level of indirection and more privacy.

Comment: Thanks even though my question was bad. Nice to see apple leading, I wish Google would take up the challenge.